# Failed transaction, but my wallet shows 0 balance

Tags: transactions, wallet, balance

I made a mistake 10 days ago when I sent some bitcoin from my wallet to another one. The problem is, because this transaction was my first one, I set the transaction fee to the bare minimum. You can guess, that I did not see my BTC since then.

According to blockchain.com, the transaction has failed, and my address has all the BTC that I wanted to sent. So far so good, but in the wallet (Atomic Wallet), my balance is near 0. I asked the support, but I didn't get any useful information, just to wait... as I said, it happened 10 days ago.
Next, I created a new wallet in Trust Wallet, add the 12 phrase seed which I get from Atomic, hoping, that its only an Atomic bug but... Trust showed near 0 balance too.

So here is my question: how can I get back my BTC from the blockhain universe? I read something about Replace By Fee and Child Pays For Parent methods, but I'm not sure that these can help me. Or am I wrong?

The [transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/1708b559f0c40e250d28c85bfcc2e959be8577679fb8f6ca22108883c8935604).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Not really. My transaction has failed and my BTC is sitting on my address, but Atomic Wallet does not see the balance, nor the Trust Wallet. This is beyond confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Blockchain record for address
1MhnRVvDTHGMSRdSRU5sP7vFH3aMExBAc9](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1MhnRVvDTHGMSRdSRU5sP7vFH3aMExBAc9)

| Date | Transaction ID | Confirms | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-25 12:56 | 8c038b...c3fb2f | 2691 | Money received from bc1qq9...6cfvgq |
| 2021-02-02 15:33 | 1708b5...935604 | 0 | Failed low-fee transaction, now invalid |
| 2021-02-12 14:08 | a77bb6...26273d | 5 | Money sent to 1EqnaM...WQGW6y |

> how can I get back my BTC from the blockhain universe?

Whoever knows the private key for address
1EqnaMiP676iSxMASjtKimz1k6GbWQGW6y now has control over that money.